# SQLContext implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning spark and scala. I am well versed in java, but not so much in scala. I am going through a tutorial on spark, and came across the following line of code, which has not been explained:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

(`sc` is the SparkContext instance)

I know the concepts behind scala implicits (atleast I think I know). Could somebody explain to me what exactly is meant by the `import` statement above? What `implicits` are bound to the `sqlContext` instance when it is instantiated and how? Are these implicits defined inside the SQLContext class?

**EDIT**
The following seems to work for me as well (fresh code):

```
val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

In this code just above. what exactly is sqlContext and where is it defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.implicits$.html):
`sqlContext.implicits` contains "(Scala-specific) Implicit methods available in Scala for converting common Scala objects into DataFrames. "

And is also explained in [Spark programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sqlcontext):

```
// this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame.
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

For example in the code below `.toDF()` won't work unless you will import `sqlContext.implicits`:

```
val airports = sc.makeRDD(Source.fromFile(airportsPath).getLines().drop(1).toSeq, 1)
    .map(s => s.replaceAll("\"", "").split(","))
    .map(a => Airport(a(0), a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4), a(5), a(6)))
    .toDF()
```

> What implicits are bound to the sqlContext instance when it is
>   instantiated and how? Are these implicits defined inside the SQLContext class?

Yes they are defined in object `implicits` inside `SqlContext` class, which extends [SQLImplicits.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala). It looks there are two types of implicit conversions defined there:

1. RDD to DataFrameHolder conversion, which enables using above mentioned `rdd.toDf()`.
2. Various instances of [Encoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder) which are "Used to convert a JVM object of type T to and from the internal Spark SQL representation."

Comment: Yes, but is `sqlContext` predefined?? I just created an object `sqlContext` of the class `SQLContext` above.

Comment: What do you mean by sqlContext predefined?

Comment: Is there a version of `sqlContext` already defined in the Spark API, that is different from the `sqlContext` that is being defined above?

Comment: Well, there's also HiveContext, which extends SqlContext. If you are talking about actual instances, then no, there's no other instance, and you'll have to create your own.

Comment: I got it. SQL context is available as sqlContext in the spark shell. Just like SparkContext instance is available as sc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105779/discussion-between-ankit-khettry-and-vitalii).

Comment: On a related note, since I don't want to post another question separately, why is it that `import SQLContext.implicits._` throws an error, but `import sqlContext.implicits._` does not?

Comment: because `implicits` defined in *class* sqlcontext, not in object, and in Scala you need to create an instance of a class before using it. Also class sqlcontext require existing sparkContext, so it cannot be defined as an object.